# Simple C++ pointer confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void changeStr(char *str)
{
    str = "D";
}

void changeStr(char **str)
{
    *str = "S";
}

    char str[] = "Good";
    changeStr(str); 
    cout<<str<<endl;
    char *p = str;
    //*p = 'j';
    changeStr(&p);
    cout<<str<<endl;
```

I just try to change the value of `str[]` that array. WITHOUT RETURN!

I think  the first `changeStr` just pass in pointer of `str`, and change that value, but actually it did not change it.

The second I use pointer of pointer but also cannot work.

Comment: Pick up a book and read a little more about strings, pointers and char arrays.

Comment: The second version changes `p`, but doesn't change `str` in the main program. And it cannot, because `char str[]` is an array of characters, not a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take it step by step.

```
char str[] = "Good";
```

You are creating an array of characters, 5 characters long with the following content:

`{ 'G', 'o', 'o', 'd', '\0' }`

```
changeStr(str);
```

Here, you are passing that array to a function. Since arrays decay into pointers, this call is perfectly OK.

```
void changeStr(char *str)
{
    str = "D";
}
```

Now, here comes the first issue. You are probably confusing `"D"` and `'D'`. If you want to change the first character in the array you need to do it the following way:

```
str[0] = 'D';
```

This would work fine. Changing the pointer won't do anything, because it's a local variable that holds a pointer to the beginning of the array, not the array itself. If you want to replace the entire content of the array with just `{ 'D', '\0' }`, you would need to use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(str,"D");
```

Now, let's check the last part. Here you mix things up a bit.

```
char *p = str;
changeStr(&p);
```

You are creating a new variable that points to the beginning of the array and you pass pointer to that variable into the next function.

```
void changeStr(char **str)
{
    *str = "S";
}
```

Which does indeed change the original variable passed, but remember, this is `p` not the array. What you did is change where `p` points. It now points to a constant `"S"`.

Comment: for first issue, i know char* str is just first character of array, it that pass in the pointer or just copy of fist element of array(namely 'G'), i think it is pointer(maybe because that variable has *)?

Answer (score 1):

In the first version of the `changeStr` function, the argument `str` is considered a local variable, and as all local variables changes to them are only changed inside the actual function.

The second version passes the string as a reference. Basically this is what happens when you specify that a variable should be passed as reference with the `&` specification:

```
void changeStr(char *&str)
```

Internally the compiler passes references as pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For the value of str to change you have to pass it by reference.

It must be like

```
void changeStr(char* &str)
```

this will ensure that variable is passed by reference, thus if you make any changes to the variable in the function it will be a global change.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use assignment operator to store string in a variable even if its a pointer.
use strcpy after including string.h

```
void changeStr(char *str)
{
    strcpy(str, "D");
}
```

this should change the data to which str pointer is pointing...even in the scope where the function call was made...